# How to calculate the determinants like these?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm trying to solve this determinant question and I just can't understand how to approach this.

If $x^3$=1, then

$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\
b & c & a \\
c & a & b \end{vmatrix}$$ equals

(A) $(cx^2+bx+a)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & b & c \\
x & c & a \\
x^2 & a & b \end{vmatrix}$
(B) $(cx^2+bx+a)\begin{vmatrix} x & b & c \\
1 & c & a \\
x^2 & a & b \end{vmatrix}$

(C) $(cx^2+bx+a)\begin{vmatrix} x^2 & b & c \\
x & c & a \\
1 & a & b \end{vmatrix}$
(D) $(cx^2+bx+a)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & b & c \\
x^2 & c & a \\
x & a & b \end{vmatrix}$

I don't understand the relevance of $x^3$. I can add all the rows and take out the common term, but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do here after that. Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious at first glance what's meant to me either. Are you sure that's all of the information?

Comment: Yes, this is the screenshot of the entire question. I have the answer too, would that help?

Comment: I thought maybe we were meant to multiply the determinant with x^3, but that doesn't take me very far either.

Comment: Sure, toss in the answer. Maybe it will be more clear. What is this from?

Comment: The answer is supposed to be D. And I'm solving this sample paper for an entrance exam, here : http://economicsentrance.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/0/5/1105777/msqe2006.pdf . Question 8.

Comment: @dexter, I know the answer has been posted, I have given a more general way of doing it instead of trial and error. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(D) is correct. Multiply $(cx^2+bx+a)$ in the first column, put 1 in place of $x^3$ (for example $cx^4=cx$...), then substract appropriate multiples of the second and third columns from the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Since only first column varies in the given options, replace it with (p q r), multiply $(cx^2+bx+a)$ to the first column, we get

$$\begin{vmatrix} (cx^2+bx+a)p & b & c \\
(cx^2+bx+a)q & c & a \\
(cx^2+bx+a)r & a & b \end{vmatrix}$$

Now comparing with first column of determinant and using $x^3=1$, find the values of $p$ such that $ap=a$, $q$ such that $bxq=b$, $r$ such that $cx^2r=c$.

If you want to verify the answer, try and see if some column operations $C_1-C_ix^2-C_jx\to C_1$ for $i,j\in\{1,2\}$ takes you to the determinant given in question for the values of $p,q,r$ you just found.